# PHP Index error undefined

Tags: php

I would like to capture values from the input , calculate and display the result on the same page, but for some reason I keep getting this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: inputval in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\exercise 2\exercise2-3.php on line 67

here is what I have done so far.A user enters 2+ 3 or 5 * 4 or 5-4 etc.

```
<div class="div">
    <h1>My Calculator</h1>
    <form method="POST">
    <?php

    echo "      <input type='text' name='inputval' size='15' class='inputs' /><input class='button' type='submit' name='register' value='Register'>
    </form>
    <p>";

        $string =$_POST["inputval"];
        $value = eval($string);

        echo "Result is:".$value;

        ?>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you POST a value named `inputval` to that page?

Comment: No infact, I want the result to be displayed on the same page

Comment: running `eval` on an arbitrary variable posted from your form is **very** unsecure

Comment: Am a newbie, what would you suggest?

Comment: Read the question+answer linked by @Phil and take what @scrowler mentioned extremely seriously (Google information about security issues with `eval`).

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="div">
<h1>My Calculator</h1>
<form action="" method="POST">

<input type="text" name="inputval" size="15" class="inputs">
<input class="button" type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
</form>
<p>
    <?php
    if (!empty($_POST['inputval'])) {
        $string = $_POST['inputval'];
        $value = eval($string);

        echo 'Result is: ' . $value;
    }
    ?>
</p>
```

Start the php tag later on after your input tag's instead of echo'ing them in your php script. And check for input, else the code will still run even when there is no POST.

`empty()` will check if the array == false (if no values) or it is not set `!isset()`.

`!empty()` will run when the value inside is not false or if values are set in the array.

Comment: `isset($_POST["inputval"])` would make more sense.

Comment: @Marty Indeed. In fact, `isset($_POST)` will **always** return `true`

Comment: @Phil I was trying to be subtle ;)

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. I have updated the code, this should work.

Comment: I still get the error Undefined index: inputval

Comment: right when the php tag starts put `var_dump($_POST);`. Submit a value in the form, submit, and then tell me the output.

Comment: This is what I got: array(2) { ["inputval"]=> string(5) "10+20" ["register"]=> string(8) "Register" } 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\exercise 2\exercise2-3.php(68) : eval()'d code on line 1
Result is:

Comment: What is at the end of your file?

Comment: You mean the file extension ?

Comment: At the bottom of the file in text editor

Comment: <body>
  <div class="div">
  <h1>My Calculator</h1>
  <form method="POST" action="">
  <input type='text' name='inputval' size='15' class='inputs' /><input class='button' type='submit' name='register' value='Register'>
  </form>
  <p>
   <?php
   if (isset($_POST['inputval'])) {
   $string =$_POST['inputval'];
   $value = eval('$string');

   echo 'Result is:'.$value;

   }
   
   ?>
  </p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: That's all I have nothing more

Comment: Hmm search around for 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file'

Comment: that's what I currently have: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\exercise 2\exercise2-3.php(67) : eval()'d code on line 1
Result is: